Possible boundary conditions in derivation of Euler-Lagrange equations
Given a Lagrange density
$$\mathcal{L} = g^{ij} \phi_{,i} \phi_{,j} - V(\phi)\tag{1}$$
I have read (e.g. here) that the boundary term that occurs through variation of the action
$$ \delta I = \int_V dV \, \text{EL} \, \delta \phi + \oint_{\partial V} dS \, n^i \, \partial_i \phi \, \delta \phi\tag{2}$$
vanishes for Dirichlet conditions ($\delta \phi = 0$), for homogeneous Neumann conditions ($\mathbf{n}(\phi) = 0$) AND for their combinations, i.e. Robin conditions ($ a \phi + b \mathbf{n}(\phi) = c$).
It is easy to see how Dirichlet conditions and homogeneous Neumann conditions make the boundary integral vanish. However, I do not understand how Robin conditions achieve the same thing.

My guess: write the boundary term $B$ as something like $B = \frac{1}{a+b}(a B + b B)$, use integration by parts on one of the terms, try to combine both of them to get the Robin conditions and see what it happens. I think there would be a few difficulties with this approach (maybe the combination is not straightforward), but that would be my first guess. I also think you might need homogeneous Robin conditions ($c = 0$), but I could be wrong

(that is obviously not an answer, but it could be a starting point)


As mentioned in the linked Phys.SE post there are 2 possible boundary conditions (BCs):

Essential/Dirichlet BC,

Natural BC,


which can be chosen independently for each connected components of the boundary $\partial V$.
The BC cannot change discontinuously within a connected boundary component since the field variables are usually assumed to be continuous/sufficiently differentiable due to physical reasons.
However, if there is more than 1 connected boundary components, then combinations are possible: Essential/Dirichlet BC on some connected boundary component and natural BC on the rest.
NB: The word combination should not be understood as a linear combination, cf. OP's question.

Example: In OP's action (1), the natural BC is a Neumann BC. If we add a boundary term proportional to $$\oint_{\partial V} \!dS ~ \phi^2$$ to OP's action (1), then the natural BC becomes a Robin BC.



Thank you for clarifying this. However, I have a follow-up question on this. I hope you can maybe find the time to take a look at it (see here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/819734/)
