Robin conditions from action principle
Consider the Lagrangian density
$$L(\tilde{\phi}, \nabla \tilde{\phi}, \tilde{g}) = \tilde{g}^{\mu \nu} \nabla_{\mu} \tilde{\phi} \nabla_{\nu} \tilde{\phi} + \xi \tilde{R} \tilde{\phi}^2$$
with $\tilde{R}$ being the Ricci scalar curvature with respect to the metric $\tilde{g}$ and $\xi$ being some coupling constant. Now under conformal transformations $\tilde{g} = \Omega^2 g$ and $\tilde{\phi} = \phi/\Omega$, this Lagrangian reads
$$L = \Omega^{-4} \Big[ L(\phi, \nabla \phi, g) - (6\xi-1) \Omega^{-1} \phi^2 \nabla^{\mu} \nabla_{\mu} \Omega - \nabla^{\mu} \big( \Omega^{-1} \phi^2 \nabla_{\nu} \Omega \big) \Big]$$
So that for the choice $\xi = 1/6$ one finds that the conformal transformation is a quasisymmetry of the action. If one varies the action as usual, then one finds the equation
$$\delta S = \int_{\mathcal{M}} \! \! dV \; \text{(EL-equation)} + \oint_{\partial \mathcal{M}}  \! \! dS \; n(\phi) \, \delta \phi - \oint_{\partial \mathcal{M}} \! \! dS \; \Omega^{-1} n(\Omega) \phi \, \delta \phi \tag{1}$$
So far so good. Now let's consider a specific example: An asymptotically AdS spacetime with a black hole at the origin. When choosing $\xi = 0$, then one finds that the boundary conditions $\phi = 0$ and $n(\phi) = 0$ at scri are necessary for the equations of motions to have a solution. Choosing $\xi = 1/6$, however, gives rise to a freedom in the choice of boundary conditions such that Robin conditions $a \phi + b n(\phi) = 0$ are allowed.
I assume that this last possibility must be hidden somewhere in the above boundary terms (equation (1)), but I do not see how, since these are firstly independent of the choice of $\xi$ and secondly these do not depend on the parameters $a$ and $b$.
Is there any way to rearrange the boundary terms, such that one can read off that Robin conditions are possible when having $\xi = 1/6$?
